# Insert a Row in Existing DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I tried a method for the question Asked.

```
public DataTable allSupportPoints(DataTable createPath, double rMax, double interval, int curveType)
    {
        List <DataTable> theCornerCurves = cornerCurves(createPath, rMax, interval, curveType);
        DataTable curvePoints = CustomMerge(theCornerCurves);

        double X1 = Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[0][1]);
        double Y1 = Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[0][2]);
        double X2, Y2;
        int count = curvePoints.Rows.Count;
        double theDistance;
        int pointInsert;
        for (int i = 0; i < count;)
        {
            X2 = Convert.ToDouble(theCornerCurves[i].Rows[0][0]);
            Y2 = Convert.ToDouble(theCornerCurves[i].Rows[0][0]);
            theDistance = distance(X1,Y1,X2,Y2);
            int j=0;
            if ( theDistance> interval)
            {
                pointInsert = Convert.ToInt32 (theDistance / interval);
                DataTable temp = straightLineGenerator(X1, Y1, X2, Y2,interval);
                for (j = 0; j < temp.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    var rowTemp = temp.NewRow(); 
                    rowTemp.ItemArray =    temp.Rows[j].ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
                    curvePoints.Rows.InsertAt(rowTemp, i + j);
                }
            }
            X1=Convert.ToDouble(curvePoints.Rows[i+j][0]);
            Y1 = 0;
            count = curvePoints.Rows.Count;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        return curvePoints;

    }
```

I get This runTime Error: This row already belongs to another table.
I have tried different methods to Insert yet the error is same, i referred some posts also but it doesnt seem to work
Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
for (j = 0; j < temp.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    var rowTemp = temp.NewRow(); 
    rowTemp.ItemArray = temp.Rows[j].ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
    curvePoints.Rows.InsertAt(rowTemp, i + j);
}
```

is incorrect. First you're adding new row to `temp`, and then trying to insert it into `curvePoints`. Since it already belongs to `temp` datatable - you're getting exception you've mentioned.

This code can be simplified as

```
for (j = 0; j < temp.Rows.Count; j++)
    curvePoints.ImportRow(temp.Rows[j]);
```

But note: `ImportRow` inserts row at last position, so if you really need to insert row into specific position like you're doing - just leave your code as is and only change `var rowTemp = temp.NewRow();` to `var rowTemp = curvePoints.NewRow();`

Comment: Importing Row doesn't control the location of inserted rows, it adds it like a queue (FIFO). I want to insert it at specific location. Hence InsertAt  but still I cant figure it out.

Comment: Doesn't changing  `var rowTemp = temp.NewRow();` to `var rowTemp = curvePoints.NewRow();` resolved your problem?

Comment: No, it doesnt, it throws the same error. "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: This row already belongs to another table."

Comment: I found the solution. You were right all along. I misunderstood ure solution. thanks :)

Comment: You can't vote up until your reputation less than 15. You can only mark answer as accepted (green mark below vote down arrow). Threads are usually get closed only in the case it considered as useless to someone else - so there is no need to close your thread.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
var rowTemp = temp.NewRow();
```

to this:

```
var rowTemp = curvePoints.NewRow();
```

In fact the row must be created by the same table you want to add it